# Change a TextView Visibility in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a some fragment in my PageViewer.
In the main fragment, I would like to show a component ( TextView or imageView) if there is no connection.
In the code below, I can reach my textview, but I cannot get them disapperead.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);


//      RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
    TextView TxtIsNotConnected = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.isNotConnected);
    TextView TxtIsConnected = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.isConnected);
//      String text = TxtIsNotConnected.getText().toString(); // This is a test which works, return the text o my textview.
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityUtils.isConnected(getActivity()); // This Works fine
    if (!isConnected) TxtIsNotConnected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // NOT WORKING
    else              TxtIsConnected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // NOT WORKING

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}
```

How should I do???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your TextView visible

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To make Invisible

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

From your code it seems that you have to keep one view visible and another invisible. So, please try this

```
if (!isConnected) {
TxtIsNotConnected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TxtIsConnected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   TxtIsConnected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    TxtIsNotConnected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Hope it helps...

Edit :
Well, your code is correct about visibility but you have made a silly mistake that's why it seems that your code is not working. Look at the first line and last line of your onCreateView method. You have inflated your R.layout.main in View object called "layout". You have set your actions within that layout. Finally you have returned a new instance of that view. So, your previous codes became useless. So, your return statement will be...

```
return layout ;
```

It should fix the problem.

Comment: The problem isn t the logic, the problem is I cannot update visibility! I update the code, but it stays whitout setting visibility :(